# TypeError DS.RESTAdapter is undefined when include ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sails.js

I need your help. Indeed, I'm trying to include EmberJS and ember-data to SailsJS.

For Ember I do not have any problem, but when I include ember-data I've 2 errors in my JS console :

```
TypeError: Ember.State is undefined
TypeError: DS.RESTAdapter is undefined
```

I need RESTAdapter for calling my models through REST Sails API.

Here my begin of JS code for Ember :

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Users = DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({host: '/foo'});
```

My layout.ejs is correctly loaded and - i think - the librairies included in the correct order :

```
<script src="linker/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="linker/js/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="linker/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="linker/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="linker/js/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="linker/js/ember-min.js"></script>
<script src="linker/js/ember-data-min.js"></script>
```

Thanks by advance for your help.

Cyril.

Comment: What version of Ember-Data are you using?

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your comment. The version is not specified but it's the latest from their github. In code it's written `CURRENT_API_VERSION = 10;` that's all.

Comment: Wow, that version is older than dirt in Ember-Data time. From sometime in December 2012 at far as I can tell. 1.4.0 is the latest Ember version, and 1.0.0-beta7 is the latest Ember-Data version. It's very unlikely that you'll get any help with a version that old. I suggest upgrading.

Comment: No problem for upgrading. But I found this js file on their github, so this github is not up to date ? Do you know where could I find an up to date ember-data version please ?

Comment: Their Github is up to date, but I don't think they store builds in the repo. You can get the latest versions of both Ember and Ember-Data [here](http://emberjs.com/builds/).

Comment: Thank you, but it is the Ember.js not the ember-data isn't it ?

Comment: You might have problems with both based on your errors. You definitely have problems with Ember-Data though.

Comment: I've already Ember.js 1.4.0 but apparently problems with Ember-data yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have `app.js` included *before* Ember and Ember-Data. If your code is executing upon load, neither Ember nor Ember-Data are loaded at that point. Move `app.js` so it's loaded after all of it's dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. The errors are the same as previously. Moreover, Ember is well loaded even if app.js is placed before. app.js is **not** the js file which contain my Ember code, it is a sails js file, my custom js file embedding my Ember code is well placed afeter all dependencies of Ember.